# Adding Bootstrap Plugins to Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm new to Angular and trying to figure out how to bring in a Bootstrap Plugin, specifically the [Bootstrap Toggle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-toggle), to Angular 8. Here is what I have tried.

Installed `bootstrap`, `jquery`, `popper.js`, `bootstrap-toggle`

In `angular.json` I added

```
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.css",
      "./node_modules/bootstrap-toggle/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css",
      "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "./node_modules/bootstrap-toggle/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js",
      "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ]
```

In the `app.module.ts` I added

```
import bootstrap from "bootstrap";
```

Then for testing I added the following to the `app.component.html`

```
<div class="container">
    <p> Please enter your name</p>
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12 justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input class="form-control" style="width:100%" #invitation>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>

        </div>            
    </form>
    <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
</div>
```

The checkbox is not changed to a toggle. Any ideas why?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tlghnn

Comment: Did you ever got it working? I'm facing exactly the same problem

Comment: Any updates on how you made it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add like this

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="switch1">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="switch1">Toggle me</label>
</div>
```